# Jni exception ---- Bogus method descriptor?

Tags: java-native-interface

I try to call a java method in cpp code:

In cpp code:

```
jclass    m_cls = env->FindClass("icm/bdroid/jni/Element");  
jmethodID m_mid_addElement = env->GetMethodID(m_cls,"AddElement","(icm/bdroid/jni/Element:)V");
```

The Java code:

```
public void AddElement(Element e) {
```

Get following exception:

> 12-07 04:21:00.051: W/dalvikvm(31880): Bogus method descriptor:
>   (icm/bdroid/jni/Element:)V
>
> 12-07 04:21:00.051: W/dalvikvm(31880): Bogus method descriptor:
>   (icm/bdroid/jni/Element:)V
>
> 12-07 04:21:00.051: D/dalvikvm(31880): GetMethodID: method not found:
>   Licm/bdroid/jni/Element;.AddElement:(icm/bdroid/jni/Element:)V
>
> 12-07 04:21:00.051: W/dalvikvm(31880): JNI WARNING: JNI method called
>   with exception raised
>
> 12-07 04:21:00.051: W/dalvikvm(31880):              in
>   Licm/bdroid/jni/Jni;.parseScore (J)Licm/bdroid/jni/Element;
>   (NewObjectV)

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be:

```
env->GetMethodID(m_cls,"AddElement","(Licm/bdroid/jni/Element;)V");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "Type Signatures" section of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

L fully-qualified-class ;   fully-qualified-class

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get method signatures is the javap utility:

```
javap -cp your.jar -s fully.qualified.class.Name
```